# Getting "write EPIPE" error on AWS lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, princexml

I followed this guide on https://medium.com/@bruce_39084/setting-up-prince-on-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-4d524dcb035b but I want to just pass in a url instead of a html file. so I made some changes to the index.js and installed axios. I also used the latest prince lambda package as opposed to the 13.5 included in the guide.

```
    var execFile = require('child_process').exec;
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    function tinyMultipartParser(data) {
        // assume first line is boundary
        const lines = data.split("\r\n");
        const output = [];
        let in_body = false;
        lines.forEach(line => {
            output.push(line.trim());
        })
    
        return output.join("\n");
    
    }
    exports.handler = async (event, context, done) => {
    
        if (!event || !event.body) { return done(new Error("No data.")); }
        let body = event.body;
        if (event.isBase64Encoded) {
            body = Buffer.from(body, "base64").toString("ascii");
        }
    
        const response = await axios.get(body);
        body = response.data;
        const baseUrl = 'https://embed.notMyRealDomain.com'; // Replace with actual base URL
    
         // Replace relative URLs with absolute URLs
        body = body.replace(/href="([^"]+)"/g, (match, relativeURL) => {
            const absoluteURL = new URL(relativeURL, baseUrl).toString();
            return `href="${absoluteURL}"`;
        });
    
        body = body.replace(/src="([^"]+)"/g, (match, relativeURL) => {
            const absoluteURL = new URL(relativeURL, baseUrl).toString();
            return `src="${absoluteURL}"`;
        });
    
        let html = tinyMultipartParser(body);
        let child = execFile("./prince", ["-", "-o", "-"], function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) { throw new Error(err);}
            if (err === null && (m = stderr.toString().match(/prince:\s+error:\s+([^\n]+)/))) {
                throw new Error(m[1]);
            }
            done(null, {
                "isBase64Encoded": true,
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/pdf" },
                "body": stdout.toString("base64")
            });
        });
        child.stdin.write(html);
        child.stdin.end();
    };
```

I got it to the point where the "html" variable right before it does exec on prince on both the html-file version and in the pass-in-a-url version the html variable is IDENTICAL but it only works on the html file version and errors in my pass in a url version. Through some searching it says the write EPIPE error happens when the client disconnects before the function is completed. That makes sense because when i dump the response in the client i just get "null" instead of what it usually says when there is an error but in cloud watch I get the write EPIPE error. I tried some things I found online about making it wait so and so seconds for a promise but that didn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from passing the URL directly to prince? It doesn't have to operate on a local file, it can fetch URLs directly. I think that would avoid the need to rewrite relative paths as well.

Comment: I tried that, best I could, with interpreting the existing code and I couldn't get it to work. I know with the regular executeable you can pass URLs directly as a parameter but not sure if you can do that with the lambda package.

Comment: "not sure if you can do that with the lambda package" in the code above I think you can change the execFile call to pass the URL as the first argument to Prince: execFile("./prince", ["https://embed.notMyRealDomain.com/some/path", "-o", "-"]. If you want to accept different URLs then you'd need to read that from the request sent to the Labda and probably validate that the hostname is trusted (E.g. embed.notMyRealDomain.com in this example)